# Webmin: Cannot login through nginx reverse proxy

Tags: authentication, nginx, webmin, reverse-proxy

I've created a reverse proxy for webmin through nginx to run webmin at [site domain]/webmin instead of port 10000 ([site domain]:10000).

When I go to [site domain]/webmin, the login page shows up as you'd expect-- but when I try to login, the login page simply reloads (no error message, no success). The login page has all assets (images, js, etc.) properly loaded.

Looking at /var/webmin/miniserv.log, I'm seeing:
`105.23.149.76 - - [26/Jul/2015:14:07:13 -0400] "POST //session_login.cgi HTTP/1.0" 401 2892`

Note the 401 (not authorized) error status.

Before I set up the reverse proxy, successful logins looked like this:
`145.23.98.124 - - [26/Jul/2015:13:34:38 -0400] "GET /admin/config/session_login.cgi HTTP/1.1" 401 2840
145.23.98.124 - root [26/Jul/2015:13:34:44 -0400] "POST /session_login.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 871`

My system auth log isn't getting pinged by the login attempts, so webmin isn't even making the login call via PEM (it's getting stopped before that).

Does anybody know what could explain this 401 error in my log, or more generally, what might be keeping webmin login from working?

Many thanks!

---

nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name site.example.com;
        ssl on;

        ssl_certificate [ssl cert].crt;
        ssl_certificate_key [ssl key].key;
        ssl_protocols [ssl protocols];
        ssl_ciphers [ssl ciphers];

        location /webmin {
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:10000/ https://site.example.com/webmin/;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        }
}
```

Comment: For what its worth, my configuration is the same as http://serverfault.com/questions/443482/proxying-webmin-with-nginx (as is my problem, only this fix doesn't work for me). I also found this article helpful and have tried these suggestions: http://serverfault.com/questions/98987/webmin-doesnt-work-fine-behind-reverse-proxy

Comment: If you look at your paths in the example you are giving, the problem appears to lie within the proxy itself. As a side note, this is a security risk that you are opening up. Make sure that you have secure usernames and hardened passwords and keep an eye on your Webmin log.

Comment: Thanks... I'll look more at the proxy, but any suggestions? I just posted the nginx code above for review. Thanks for the note on security... I think I'm good because webmin is behind an internal auth setup, uses good usernames and strong passwords, and two factor auth is enabled.

Comment: It has been over 12 years since I set-up a proxy- I am a semi-retired core network engineer for the major global telcom networks- still, I have probably forgotten much. I will look into your edits and see if I can find something. It might take me a while to poke around.

Comment: The only quick thing I see is that you may want to try removing the trailing slashes in your proxy settings such as *proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:10000/ https://site.example.com/webmin/* and *proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000/*. Your failed attempt had two // slashes. Worth a try.

Comment: Many thanks! Removing the trailing slash from `proxy_pass` got rid of the double slash in the log and added 'webmin' (I tried removing it from each place separately, and the trailing slashes on `proxy_redirect` had no effect on the log.

BEFORE: `[client ip] - - [27/Jul/2015:00:21:13 -0400] "POST //session_login.cgi HTTP/1.0" 401 2854`
AFTER: `[client ip] - - [27/Jul/2015:00:21:53 -0400] "GET /webmin/session_login.cgi HTTP/1.0" 401 2854
[client ip] - - [27/Jul/2015:00:22:06 -0400] "POST /webmin/session_login.cgi HTTP/1.0" 401 2854`

Comment: Glad it works!! You were smart to try each piece one at a time. That indicates to me that you will be a great webmaster/IT professional! It is a scientific approach- reason and deduction.

Comment: Thanks :-)

Unfortunately... it's not fixed. It does show /webmin/ instead of a double slash, which seems logical, but I'm not actually sure it's better. example.com/webmin/ should be proxied to example.com:10000 (i.e. example.com/webmin/test/ should show up as example.com:10000/test in the log... the /webmin shouldn't be part of the URL passed to port 10000. At least, maybe. I'm still playing but the browser behavior (aka the problem) hasn't changed.

Comment: Ah! NUTS!! I will have to think on this a bit. Nginx did not exist when I was doing network stuff, but it seems simple enough.

Comment: I am in chat. Juggling between two people though... when it rains it pours.

Comment: I noticed that in http://serverfault.com/questions/443482/proxying-webmin-with-nginx the proxy_redirect was below the proxy_pass but you have it the other way around here... not sure what difference that makes yet. Something to try.

Comment: I also noticed that you are using 127.0.0.1 where the example has $host. That could possibly make a real difference. You should avoid using 127.0.0.1 for anything web generally. It is the loopback IP address as well as localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, it works for me well:

`/etc/webmin/config`:

```
webprefix=/webmin
webprefixnoredir=1
relative_redir=0   # pay attention on this
referer=www.examle.com
```

`/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf`:

```
cookiepath=/webmin
```

nginx config:

```
location /webmin/ { 
    proxy_pass http://localhost:10000/;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

**Do not** add `proxy_set_header Host $host;`, it won't work.

Webmin should be available on http://www.examle.com/webmin/

[Source](https://github.com/webmin/webmin/issues/744#issuecomment-386294075)

Comment: It appears there may be some typos. I am not sure if they are deliberate. Can you double check? Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your web browser is naturally caching the problematic login pages and/or the headers returned for the login pages are not correct.

Check the speed of the page load. When you login and press the login button, if the load time is ridiculously fast compared to the first time the login screen has loaded, then you know that the previous page was cached and then being reloaded.

To workaround this problem temporarily, configure your web browser to disable all forms of caching and turn on cookies.

There's also a possibility that cookie values were not used at the time the page is requested after successful login. This results in every user seeing the same content as a guest would.

If you want to go more technical, then look for HTTP headers on each request using an advanced command line tool like CURL or maybe webpagetest.org may help as well, especially with page timings. The most important header to look for is:

```
Set-Cookie
```

Once the login button is selected and the correct credentials are used, then the response that is returned back to the browser should come with HTTP headers that contain `Set-Cookie` to indicate a user is logged in so that the next time a page from the same site is loaded in the same browser, a cookie is sent to the server to indicate the user has already logged in before.

And if you want to increase the chances of server requests being logged from you, just turn off caching for a while and do your testing. You might see a few repeated entries, especially if your pages always contain the same image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... good thought, but I don't think that's the issue I'm having. Used private browsing / incognito, and changed the url. It still didn't work. I checked cURL, and this is in the header:

Comment: `Set-Cookie: testing=1; path=/; httpOnly`

Comment: `pragma: no-cache Expires: Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

Comment: `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate`

Comment: `Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0`

Comment: That suggests that maybe you have the system in a special testing-only mode. The cookie that should be returned should be a unique value to the user depending on who is logged in unless logins are tracked in a server database by IP address which I don't recommend because if someone logs in on a LAN then another computer connected to the same LAN would be logged in automatically because the IP address of both computers to the world is the same.

Comment: This definitely isn't my expertise, and there may be something wrong here... but presumably there'd be a unique session identifier if I were logged in. Either way, it seems like its set to not cache (and cache is a false expiration date-- in the past). (I think?) I did a quick search, and it seems like testing=1 may be something the webmin folks left in there, but I'll check it out more thoroughly.